# What does $\{0, 1\}^*$ mean?

Tags: notation, computational-complexity

I am reading about Polynomial probabilistic time (PPT) and the input is taken from space $\{0, 1\}^*$ and I am not able to understand how is this working.

Comment: Probably the Kleene, or star-, closure of $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: Also usually the star is a superscript, i.e. $\{0,1\}^\star$.

Comment: (possibly empty) strings over the letters $\{0,1\}$

Answer (score 4):

The notation $\{0,1\}^*$ refers to the space of finite strings in the alphabet $\{0,1\}$, including the empty string.